# Python2 and Python3: exact same tunnel behaves differently when using one or the other

Tags: python, tunnel

I have two scripts, one for Python 2 and one for Python 3.
The intention is that they do *exactly* the same and produce the exact same tunnel.
However, the tunnel receives and forwards traffic in Python 2 but only receives and does not forward the exact same traffic with the Python 3 script.

The code in python 2 is:

```
IFF_TUN       = 0x0001
TUNSETIFF     = 0x400454ca
TUN_FILE      = '/dev/net/tun'
CMD_IFCONFIG  = '/sbin/ifconfig'
CMD_ROUTE     = '/sbin/route'
DUMMY_PREFIX  = 'dead:dead:dead'

class NullLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        pass

class NetworkSideThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,username,lowpan,prefix,callbackActivity,callbackDisconnected):

        # record params
        self.username         = username
        self.lowpan           = lowpan
        self.prefix           = prefix
        self.callbackActivity = callbackActivity
        self.callbackDisconnected = callbackDisconnected

        # variables
        self.disconnectNow = False

        # logging
        self.log           = logging.getLogger(self.username+'_NetworkSideThread')
        if len(self.log.handlers)==0:
            self.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            self.log.addHandler(NullLogHandler())

        # create virtual interface
        self.virtualIf = os.open(TUN_FILE, os.O_RDWR)
        ifs = ioctl(self.virtualIf, TUNSETIFF, struct.pack("16sH", "tun%d", IFF_TUN))
        self.ifname = ifs[:16].strip(b"\x00")
        print('Created virtual interface '+self.ifname+'.'+'.')

        # configure IPv6 addresses of virtual interface
        os.system(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' up')
        os.system(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' inet6 add ' + self.prefix + '::1/64')
        os.system(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' inet6 add fe80::1/64')
        print('Configured IPv6 address')

        # set static route
        os.system(CMD_ROUTE+' -A inet6 add ' + self.prefix + '::/64 dev ' + self.ifname)
        print('Set up static route.')

        # initialize parent class
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        # set thread name
        self.setName('NetworkSideThread for '+self.username)

        # thread daemon mode
        self.setDaemon(True)
```

And in Python3:

```
IFF_TUN       = 0x0001
TUNSETIFF     = 0x400454ca
TUN_FILE      = '/dev/net/tun'
CMD_IFCONFIG  = '/sbin/ifconfig'
CMD_ROUTE     = '/sbin/route'
DEV_NULL      = '/dev/null'
CMD_PING6     = 'ping6'
DUMMY_PREFIX  = 'dead:dead:dead'

class NullLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        pass

class NetworkSideThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,username,lowpan,prefix,callbackActivity,callbackDisconnected):

        # record params
        self.username         = username
        self.lowpan           = lowpan
        self.prefix           = prefix
        self.callbackActivity = callbackActivity
        self.callbackDisconnected = callbackDisconnected

        # variables
        self.disconnectNow = False

        # logging
        self.log           = logging.getLogger(self.username+'_NetworkSideThread')
        if len(self.log.handlers)==0:
            self.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            self.log.addHandler(NullLogHandler())

        # create virtual interface
        self.virtualIf = os.open(TUN_FILE, os.O_RDWR, mode=0o777)
        os.set_inheritable(self.virtualIf, True)
        tun_name = 'tun0'.encode()
        ifs = ioctl(self.virtualIf, TUNSETIFF, struct.pack("16sH", tun_name, IFF_TUN))
        self.ifname = tun_name.decode
        print('Created virtual interface '+self.ifname+'.'+'.')

        # configure IPv6 addresses of virtual interface
        os.system(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' up')
        os.system(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' inet6 add ' + self.prefix + '::1/64')
        os.system(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' inet6 add fe80::1/64')
        print('Configured IPv6 address')

        # set static route
        os.system(CMD_ROUTE+' -A inet6 add ' + self.prefix + '::/64 dev ' + self.ifname)
        print('Set up static route.')

        # initialize parent class
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        # set thread name
        self.setName('NetworkSideThread for '+self.username)

        # thread daemon mode
        self.setDaemon(True)
```

As far as I can tell they both make a tun0 which is identical when looking at it through ifconfig.
I did notice though that making a tunnel through os.open returns a different file descriptor for the same path when using Python 2 versus Python 3, namely 9 and 17. This seems odd, is that normal?

If that is unrelated, any advice on how to fix this issue? The tunnel looks identical but does not do the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
The problem was NOT with the tunnel but with how the packets were written to the tunnel.

I should have added, or not required, a tunnel header before writing the packet to the tunnel.

Specifically, using IFF_TUN       = 0x0001 | 0x1000 and not adding 4B for the tunnel header solves the problem.